# Does Azure Media Services have a list of supported video encoding MIME Types?

Tags: azure, mime-types, azure-media-services, video-codecs

Azure media services supports the following:

[Input container/file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-encoder-standard-formats#input-containerfile-formats)

[Input video codecs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-encoder-standard-formats#input-video-codecs)

I have a need to guard Video Uploads based on MIME Type.

Is there a direct conversion from the above [Container and Codec] to MIME Type and or is there documentation or a library for such?

Thanks

Comment: This document tell us how to create a transform with a custom preset. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/media-services/latest/customize-encoder-presets-how-to#create-a-transform-with-a-custom-preset

Comment: I think you it will help you to upload your media file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list at https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#video for different video MIME types, but a lot of applications will simply use video/mp4 for any sort of H.264 or H.265 encoded video for example.  This means that often there is no direct mapping between file extension or MIME to container or codec.  To be more accurate you'd have to read the file header and then determine the actual file type.  Additionally, keep in mind that when you are uploading content to Media Services that you are actually uploading that content to Azure Storage which will accept just about anything.

Comment: Currently our product has an Angular Client that uploads videos to our server -> blob storage for deferred processing via AMS.  We convert all to .H264.  Deferred processing means invalid formats do not error synchronously.  Reading file header to determine type is more accurate, but we can find no existing JS solution for such and we are looking for a more maintainable solution.  We don't need 100% accuracy.

Comment: Additionally, the referenced Media types link you provided does not include `video/webm` for example which is now common.  We are considering removing our "allow-list" and switching to a "disallow-list" if and when any are encountered.  The outcome of this SO will inform that decision.

Comment: Relying on MIME type just isn't a great way of assuming what's inside of a video because of the multiple layers of what's inside.  As I mentioned, cracking open the header is probably going to be one of the only ways to provide any sort of reliability at all.  Using something like FFMPEG / FFPROBE on your server to output information could be an option.